# jQuery Tablesorter *Pager* not working if used fom AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

The code inside the DIV search_status works with sorting and pagination once the page has loaded, however if I call the exact same data from an ajax call to replace the content the sorting still works however the pagination breaks. Any ideas anyone as to why this would happen and how I could fix?

**EDIT: Adding the below fixes the issue.**

```
$("#tablesorter").tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false });
```

-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tablesorter").tablesorter({ debug: false, widgets: ['zebra', 'columnHighlight'] })
    .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false });
});
$(function() {
    if ($("#search").val()!=''){
        asearch();
    }
    function asearch() {
        $.post("/_ajax/search_table",{
            search: $("#search").val()
        },
        function(data){
            $("#search_status").html(data);
            $("#tablesorter").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});
        });
        return false;
    }
    $("#button_search").click(function() {
        asearch();
    });
    $('#search').bind('keydown',function(e){ 
        if (e.keyCode==13 || e.which==13) asearch();
    });
});
}
</script>
Search&nbsp;<input id="search" name="search" type="text">&nbsp;<input id="button_search" type="button" value="Search">
<div id="search_status" style="text-align:left">

    <table cellspacing="1" id="tablesorter" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr align="center">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr id="pager" align="center">
                <td colspan="7">
                    <img src="/images/first.png" class="first" alt="First Page" height="16" width="16">
                    <img src="/images/prev.png" class="prev" alt="Previous Page" height="16" width="16">
                    &nbsp;<label class="pagedisplay"></label>&nbsp;<img src="/images/next.png" class="next" alt="Next Page" height="16" width="16">
                    <img src="/images/last.png" class="last" alt="Last Page" height="16" width="16">
                    <select class="pagesize">
                        <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><a href="javascript:set_selection('2');">2</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:set_selection('2');">John</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><a href="javascript:set_selection('1');">1</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:set_selection('1');">Doe</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the pager and the table sorter in general when loading the table with an ajax call. After trying a few different suggestions (none that worked completely) I found puting the JQuery tablesorter script in my partial view and not in the main view did the trick.

In the main view

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#ajaxBusy').show();
        $('#details').hide();
        $('#pager').hide();
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
        $('#details').show();
        $('#pager').show();
    });
```

....

});

```
function SearchCustomerStock(force) {
    var searchText = $("#FindStock_ED").val();
    var customerId = '@ViewBag.EncodedID';
    if (force || searchText.length > 2) {
        $('#ajaxBusy').show();
        $('#details').hide();
        var dataObject = { CustomerId: customerId, Like: searchText, Perspective: $('#Perspective').val(), PerspectiveId: $('#PerspectiveId').val() };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/CustomerStock/GetStockLike",
            data: dataObject,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //$('#ajaxBusy').hide();
                //$('#details').show();
                $('#details').html(data);
                /*var sorting = [[0, 0]];
                $("table.tablesorter")
                            .tablesorter(
                                { widthFixed: true },
                                { sortList: [[0, 0]] },
                                { headers: { 7: { sorter: false } } })
                            .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val() });*/
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
                $('#details').show();
                alert(jqXHR + ', ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
    //$("#FindStock_ED").attr('disabled', false);
    return false;
}
```

In the partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<SkyPortR.Models.CustomerStockViewModel>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("table.tablesorter")
   .tablesorter(
       { widthFixed: true },
       { sortList: [[0, 0]] },
       { headers: { 7: { sorter: false } } })
   .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val() });

</script>

<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Barcode
        </th>
        <th>
            Alternate Code
        </th>
        <th>
            Group
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Packsize
        </th>
        <th>
            LastCost
        </th>
        <th>
            Supplier
        </th>
        <th class="indexImages">
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
```